# My output render is black when using cycles but works fine with eevee

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I am struggling to find an answer to this. I am new to blender and still learning the ropes. I don't use compositing. All I use is an HDR image for the lighting. I have attached the screenshot from Cycles below.

[image: this is what i am getting as output]

Comment: This could be quite a few things. We're going to need more information. When you say 'EEVEE' is that just the material preview, in the viewport?  Could you show us the good render, maybe the node tree? Better yet, share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @RobinBetts  No not the material preview the eevee rendering engine which is next to cycles in the drop down. But the render it works when i am viewing cycles with my CPU instead of GPU. I am unable to upload it on blend exchange can you download it from here  https://file.io/u5k86XMCK0i2 . Thank you for replying.